# Spring Cloud Data Flow support of Swarm

Tags: docker-swarm, spring-cloud-dataflow

Currently I can see that Spring Cloud Data Flow has these servers: Local, YARN, Cloud Foundry, Mesos, and Kubernetes; is there any plan for Swarm support?

Answer (score 2):

Caleb: Spring Cloud Data Flow's deployer implementation is based on [Spring Cloud Deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer)'s service provider interface (SPI), so there's currently SPI implementation for Local, CF, Yarn, Kubernetes, and Mesos. These implementations are managed in [separate repos](https://github.com/spring-cloud?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=deployer), too.

This decoupling provides flexibility and it is easy to extend to add new deployers. Though we haven't attempted to add Docker Swarm deployer yet, we would love to review contributions from the community.